# Estou programando para PHONEGAP e o JQUERY MOBILE não funciona nas paginas que faço loading

Tags: apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Estou programando para PHONEGAP e quando carrego uma página por load dentro do meu código não consigo utilizar nenhum tipo de seletor ou Jquery para aquele código.

Exemplo

```
    <script>
    (document).ready{function(){
        ("#botao1").click(
        //acao
        )
    }}

    function carregar(){
      ("#minhadiv").load("pagina.html");
    }
    </script>
```

O código da página "pagina.html" seria assim:

```
    <div id="div1">
        <span id="botao1"></span>
    </div>
```

Quando a página carrega, ao clicar no "botao1" o jquery não funciona